# Numpy function to find the best candidate to minimize a function

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I often need to find the *value that will minimize some function* from an array. To be a bit more specific, I have an `objective` function, that could  be anything, for example :

```py
def objective_function(some_value):

    @np.vectorize
    def some_arbitrary_function(x):
        return x%some_value

    return some_arbitrary_function
```

I would like a function **within numpy** that would do more or less the following:

```py
def mymin(values, key=None):
    if key is None:
        return np.min(values)
    best_index = np.argmin(key(values))
    return values[best_index]
```

This would be similar to the `sort` functions we are all used to (in both cases the `key` argument is here to specify how to sort/compute the min).

Using these would look like this:

```py
>>> objective = objective_function(6)
>>> candidates = np.array([2, 7, 9, 10, 15])
>>> mymin(candidates, key=objective)
7
```

I feel like I'm missing something as this probably exists in numpy (just like it does for sorting). Note that I'm not looking for a way to compute efficiently the `objective` function but rather to find a way to do both `argmin` and indexing in one go. Again, when we want to sort some array `x` based on a criteria `f`, we don't sort `f(x)` then map the initial values to their correct places ourselves. We just sort `x` based on values from `f(x)` : using `sort(x, key=f)`. I wonder if something similar exists **within numpy** for `min`.

Comment: Why not evaluate the function over the entire vector and then take the min ? Is it for the sake of generality (in case you want something else than the minimum)?

Comment: Ah maybe that wasn’t clear, I’m interested in the index to original value part. I could indeed apply a vectorized version of my function before getting the argmin, but then I would still need to get the original value back using the index. I was wondering if there was a way to find the min index and convert it to the value in a single function call.

Comment: Indeed, it was not. Your function returns `values[best_index]`, not `best_index`.

Comment: Yes that’s because I don’t want the index, i want the array’s value before key was applied. So I don’t want *min*, nor *argmin*, I want *v* from the array such that *key(v) leq key(u)* for any *u* in the array.

Comment: Now I'd say it is clearer what you have in mind. Still, could you clarify on what would be the advantage over simply applying `argmin` to the return value of a function? What you describe does not alter the behaviour of `argmin`; imho it's still a 2-step procedure.

Comment: If you apply `argmin` to the return value of a function `f` you only have the index `i` of `x` in `values` such that `f(x) < f(y)` for all `y`. But you don't have `x`. To get `x` you need to need to call `values[i]`. Which is exactly what I want to avoid doing here (as it seems natural to me to have both in a unique function, again, just like `sort` offers a `key` optional argument).